# Command that's only available to the owner of the bot, but bot will send the message to every guild it is in

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Make a command that's only available for the owner of the bot to use, but the bot will send the message said by the user to every guild.bot is in. I am also doing python for this.

My Code:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from keep_alive import keep_alive
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
prefix = os.environ['PREFIX']


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord. Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='Nothing <3'))

@client.event
async def owner(x):
  if x.author.id == '751535313167581265':
      return
  if x.content.startswith(owner_prefix + 'x'):
      await x.channel.send(f'Test completed')

keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

I am trying to do this owner command, but it fails and says, something close to the object is not in the argument. Please correct my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that aren't quite right in your code.

1. You're using `client.event` instead of `client.command`. While it is possible to use `client.event` it would make your life easier if you used `client.command`.
2. Variable `x`. This is not a good variable. In an `on_message` event, this would be `message`. In a command, this would be `discord.ext.commands.Context` aka `ctx`.
3. The attribute `id` of `author` is an integer. You are checking for a string.
4. Looking at your code, I don't think `owner_prefix` is defined (correct me if I'm wrong).

Before you start coding such things, you should first learn the basics. This could be through the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or online tutorials.

```
@client.command() # 1.
async def owner(ctx, arg=None): # 2.
  if ctx.author.id == 751535313167581265: # 3.
      return
  else:
      await ctx.channel.send(arg) #The usage of f-string was also useless here
```

I apologise for my past carelessness, in order to use `@client.command()`, you have to use [discord.ext.commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot). [discord.Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#client) doesn't have a method `command`, hence the error. Since `Bot` is a subclass of Client, you can use all of the `Client` functionality with the `Bot` instance.

```
from discord.ext import commands
#rest of imports
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

prefix = os.environ['PREFIX']
client = commands.bot(prefix, intents=intents)
```

A variable name is a just a variable name. To not confuse you or anyone else who reads your code, you could change `client` to `bot` and likewise `@client.command()` would be `@bot.command()`.

Comment: PS: You do not have to tell me everything that you are doing. All you have to do is try it and see, and come back to comment if you have any further queries. Also, do not post comments as answers on a question like you did. Welcome to StackOverflow.